# Check type existence in Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the most Pythonic way of determining if an object's type is contained in a specific module?

For example, let's say I want to match date, time, and datetime classes from the datetime module.

```
import datetime
mylist = [obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
for obj in mylist:
    if type(obj) in [datetime.datetime, datetime.time, datetime.date]:
        #Do thing
```

It seems silly creating a matching instance of the three for each loop. Is there some simpler way of saying "if type(obj) in some-module"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) can check against multiple types:

> `isinstance(object, classinfo)`
>
> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the `classinfo` argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns false. **If `classinfo` is a tuple of type objects (or recursively, other such tuples), return true if object is an instance of any of the types**. If `classinfo` is not a type or tuple of types and such tuples, a `TypeError` exception is raised.

```
if isinstance(obj, (datetime.datetime, datetime.time, datetime.date)):
```

Comment: In this specific case it's even possible to just check for `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` since `datetime.datetime`'s parent class is `datetime.date`.